# How to localize Parse push notifications?

Tags: parse-platform, localization, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

It looks like Apple already has built-in functionality to localize PUSH notifications by including loc-key in the aps payload. However, I don't believe Parse's iOS SDK allows you to set that key yourself using sendPushInBackground. Is there any way to localize PUSHs using Parse without first routing to my own server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert key in the data dictionary used with PFPush can be set to a dictionary instead of a string.

For anyone who finds this in the future, mine looked like this:

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @{@"loc-key":@"NEW_MESSAGE_PUSH", @"loc-args":@[sender.name]}, @"alert",
                      @"default", @"sound",
                      @"Increment", @"badge",
                      sender.pid, @"senderID",
                      nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:author];
NSString *key = @"PUSH_LOC_KEY_SEND_TO_AUTHOR";
NSArray *args = @[name] 
 NSDictionary *data = @{
                        @"alert": @{@"loc-key": key,
                                       @"loc-args": args},
                           @"badge": @"Increment",
                           @"sound": @"default"
                           };
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:pushQuery];
[push setData:data];
```

Then in Localizable.strings(Base) add:

```
"PUSH_LOC_KEY_SEND_TO_AUTHOR" = "%@ sent you a message";
```

in Localizable.strings(French) add:

```
"PUSH_LOC_KEY_SEND_TO_AUTHOR" = "%@ vous envoyé un message";
```

And note, that after you user authorises app, you should add current user object to installation so we can PFQuery him (as shown above):

```
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
[installation saveEventually];
```